# GWT: Get constants in server side

Tags: gwt, properties, constants

I'm trying to get the constants (ConstantsWithLookup) stored in the client side in my server side, but it can't figure out how to do it. I have my constants interface and my constants properties in the same folder.

I've tried tips of other similar threads with no success.

I tried Hermes, gwt-i18n-server, gwt-dmesg, GTWI18N, using a ResourceBundle, trying to get source file properties.

For the first two, it seems that the main reason is the outdated support for the newest GWT version. As for the ResourceBundle, it cannot find the properties file because at deployment, there isn't a properties file, just a Constants.class.

I'm trying to avoid changing my properties file to another location (like /WEB-INF/constants).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using [Hermes](https://github.com/MaliciousMonkey/Hermes) with GWT 2.5.0.rc1, and it works fine. Usage:

- put hermes-1.2.0.jar into war/WEB-INF/lib
- Then on the server side write something like

```java
MyConstantsWithLookup my = Hermes.get(MyConstantsWithLookup.class, "de");
String string = my.getString(key);
```

- A properties file `MyConstantsWithLookup.properties` *must* exist in the same package as `MyConstantsWithLookup.java`, even if that properties file is empty (which might be the case if you're using @DefaultStringValue etc.)
- Also add `MyConstantsWithLookup_de.properties` etc.
- **Make sure, that these properties files are copied** next to your classes when compiling. Javac doesn't do that, so it must be done in an additional build step (Eclipse usually does this automatically, but it won't happen by itself when you build e.g. with Ant)
- Many build setups will skip the java and properties files from the "client" package when compiling the server side. In that case, put your constants files in the "shared" package (if you have one).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I managed to copy the files via the copy command in my build.xml file. Everything works fine but when it tries to get the string i get the error: GWT.create() is only usable in client code!  It cannot be called, for example, from server code. Am i missing something?

Comment: On the server side, you must use `Hermes.get(MyConstantsWithLookup.class, myLanguageCode)` **instead** of GWT.create(MyConstantsWithLookup.class).

Comment: Yes, that's what I did and somehow I keep getting that error. Do i have to set something in my EntryPoint class and xml module as in gwt-i18n-server?

Comment: No, you are definitely calling GWT.create() somewhere on the server side (probably in some class in a client package, but **executed** by the server). Look at the stack trace, it should tell you where that happens!  For Hermes, just make sure that you use different code on the server (Hermes.get()) and client side (GWT.create()). (With gwt-i18n-server, it's the same, but you *can* use `LocaleFactory.get(Class<T extends LocalizableResource> cls)` **both** on the server and client side, if you set this up in your gwt.xml file etc. But that's optional, and not available AFAIK in Hermes.)

Comment: Indeed I had. As I was focusing on the server side only, I wasn't aware that I was instantiating my constants class with GWT.create() to make it easier and simple to call it from my other classes. When I commented that out and fixed my other classes, everything worked perfectly. Thank you!